# RXJS: How to use takeUntil until another Observable completes (and not emits)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have two Observables:

**1:** counts up a value and completes. (important: May complete before ever emitting any value!)

**2:** does stuff until 1 COMPLETES (not emits)

How would you implement this in RxJS?

My first try is using last() like:

```
firstObservable.pipe(
    takeUntil(secondObservable.pipe(last()))
  ).subscribe(count =>{
    //do stuff with count
  });
```

But the prroblem arises when firstObservable completes without ever emitting any value.
An error is raised:

```
Error: no elements in sequence
```

**Question**: How can i use takeUntil (or any other operator) to stop the subscription after observable 2 completed and not throw an error when no last value ever was emitted?

Comment: So the observable 2 will wait for the observable 1 to complete?

Answer (score 3):

You can use finalize on the `secondOvservable` and complete the `firstObservable` there. That way it does not depends on any value emitted, just on the complete event.

```
secondOvservable.pipe(
  finalize(() => firstObservable.complete())
).subscribe(count =>{
  //do stuff with count
});
```

Comment: I was tinkering with finalize and had 2 issues with it: first it felt "wrong" abusing it to do something as simple as waiting for an observable to complete. second finalize seems not to get called when an observable ONLY completes and next() never is called or am i mistaking? here is a stackblitz showing this (toggle line 12 for effect): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-sysuam?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Comment: I edited your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qwfrca?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a pattern that I find useful to trigger `takeUntil()` with arbitrary events. You basically create a 2nd observable "terminateSignal$" that you control directly.

```
const terminateSignal$ = new Subject<void>();
secondObservable.subscribe({
  complete: () => terminateSignal$.next()
});

firstObservable
  .pipe(takeUntil(terminateSignal$))
  .subscribe( /* do stuff */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize the observable in order to receive notifications of type: Next, Error, Complete. Then simply filter them out.

```js
 takeUntil(yourObs$.pipe(materialize(), filter(x=> x.kind === 'C'))))
```